# top 8 foley pit surfaces?

Tags: foley, surfaces, workflow

imagine you had a pair of foley pits that were 8 feet long, 2 feet wide, and about a foot deep.

each pit would be divided into 4 parts.  the middle space between the pits would be exposed foundational concrete, so scratch that one off the list.

given all of that, which 8 surfaces would you put into the pit?

Answer (score 7):

1. Carpet
2. Wood
3. Linoleum
4. Sheet Metal
5. Water
6. Sand
7. Gravel
8. Dry earth

Comment: Water is a good one! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

1. hard-wood floor
2. carpet
3. linoleum
4. tile
5. coarse dirt/earth
6. sandy loam or sand
7. asphalt/blacktop
8. lined/sealed deep empty pit with interchangeable covers
   a. metal grate
   b. metal plate (i.e. "diamond-plate")
   c. wood planks
   e. can also be used as a water pit, hence the "deep" descriptor (though you'd need some sort of pump to empty it)

I'd also keep some loose gravel stashed in a bin for use with the dirt and asphalt/blacktop pits. I'd probably keep a shop vac handy too.

Comment: hard wood floor and carpet are covered oustide of the pits with no problem.  Asphalt is interesting though... I wonder if asphalt could be just layered onto a 2'x2' concrete slab with carpet bottom though.  concrete itself doesn't work that way because its ringy, but asphalt just might.

Answer (score 0):

i'd say hardwood/wood plank is still in play. hardwood floors in a traditional hardwood floored house sound much different than prefab wood floors over concrete slab. it's a lifted hollow sound rather than the thin hard sound.

i'd also look at a strip of artificial grass that could have dirt layered in it. not astroturf but the synthetic grass.

http://www.syntheticgrasspros.com/

Comment: that's very true about the hardwood, but I wonder if that sound has to be achieved in a pit vs as a surface that can just be layed on the ground.  astroturf looks cool!